# Optimising Prefix Sum

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question: Starting with a 1-indexed array of zeros and a list of operations, for each operation add a value to each the array element between two given indices, inclusive. Once all operations have been performed, return the maximum value in the array.

Given some queries in the form [a,b,k]:

```
[[1,5,3],[4,8,7],[6,9,1]]
```

Add the values of k between the indices a and b inclusive:

```
[0,0,0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0]
[3,3,3, 3, 3,0,0,0,0, 0]
[3,3,3,10,10,7,7,7,0, 0]
[3,3,3,10,10,8,8,8,1, 0]
```

And then return the max value which is 10

My attempt is:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def Operations(size, Array):

    values = [0] * (size+2)
    for a,b,k in Array:
        values[a] += k
        values[b+1] -= k

    values = list(accumulate(values))

    Result = max(values)
    return Result




def main():
    nm = input().split()

    n = int(nm[0])

    m = int(nm[1])

    queries = []

    for _ in range(m):
        queries.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))

    result = Operations(n, queries)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code works, however, hits runtime errors when the arrays get too large. I have no idea how to lower the runtime further.

Example input is as follows:

```
5 3
1 2 100
2 5 100
3 4 100
```

Comment: How big is the input? Is it a runtime error or a time limit exceeded error? If it is a coding challenge please post the link.

Comment: Here is the question: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem?filter=python3&filter_on=language&h_l=interview&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&limit=100&page=6&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution looks good, my suggestions:

- **Generators**: the function [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) returns a generator which doesn't create the whole list in memory, but calling `list` on it does create the actual list in memory. This is probably why you get the runtime error. Changing `Operations` from:

  ```
  def Operations(size, Array):

      values = [0] * (size+2)
      for a,b,k in Array:
          values[a] += k
          values[b+1] -= k

      values = list(accumulate(values))

      Result = max(values)
      return Result
  ```

  To:

  ```
  def Operations(size, Array):
      values = [0] * (size + 2)
      for a, b, k in Array:
          values[a] += k
          values[b + 1] -= k
      return max(accumulate(values))
  ```

  solves the problem and all tests pass.
- **PEP 8**: function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability. Variable names follow the same convention as function names. [More info](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names). The function name is probably given by HackerRank, but the variable names `Array` and `Result` should be lowercase.

FYI, [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251001/227157) is my old review on the same problem.